# problema con las lineas guias de indentación de Apache Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Cada que escribo una linea de código, las lineas guias se ponen detras de las letras y no se alinean junto a mi codigo, he reinstalado el [apache-netbeans](/questions/tagged/apache-netbeans) y el [jdk](/questions/tagged/jdk) pero cuando abro un proyecto, el problema sigue.
Alguien sabe como solucionar ese problema???[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Adjunto foto para que me entiendan.

Comment: Buenas @Juan Carlo LV, te comento que siempre que escribas una pregunta, en vez de adjuntar el código como imagen lo añadas como tengo entre ```codigo``` para que el resto de personas puedan copiarlo y "jugar" con el ! Porfavor actualiza la pregunta.

Comment: Esas líneas guía indican que en la configuración de netbeans tienes que la indentación equivale a N espacios e igual, tu código está creado con otra identación. De pronto usaste tabulaciones o lo contrario.

Answer (score 1):

El problema reside en la fuente que usas, para programar la mayoria de programadores preferimos fuentes monoespaciadas, ya que cada caracter tiene el mismo espacio.

Para cambiar la fuente del editor ve a

[image: Tools > Options]

y luego a

[image: Fonts & Colors > Syntax]

Y si a pesar de ello quisieras usar alguna fuente no monoespaciada puedes mejorar la forma en que se renderiza agregando las siguientes lineas como parametro en el [archivo de configuracion de netbeans para renderizar mejor al anti-alizado](https://g3n1k.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/enabling-anti-aliasing-netbeans-editor/).

```
-J-Dswing.aatext=true 
-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias bro, de verdad estaba fatigado por este detalle
Ya que me molestaba visualmente y la indentacion se veia afectada igual
Se que la solucion es sencilla o muy basica, pero no sabia que el tipo de letra afectaba de esta forma
Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue util, te agradeceria le dieras click en el boton de triangulo hacia arriba a la izquierda, si resolvio tu problema en el boton con forma de palomita. Saludos.